# How to get fully expanded variables out of configure?

Tags: variables, autoconf, configure, expand

I created a configure.ac file like this:

```
AC_INIT()
set
```

the purpose of this is to print every available environment variable the configure script creates using `set`, so I do this:

```
user@host:~$ autoconf
user@host:~$ ./configure
```

which prints a bunch of variables like

```
build=
cache_file=/dev/null
IFS='   
'
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=C
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
no_create=
```

So far so good.
The problem is:

1. I want to expand the variables like `${prefix}/share` - but piping
   everything to a file `example.sh` and executing it using bash doesn't work, because bash complains about modifying read-only variables like `UID` and expansion itself doesn't seem to work either.
2. I tried using a `makefile` for this where expansion works, but it complains about newlines in strings, like in the above output the line `IFS=' causes an error message Makefile:24: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Does anyone have an idea how to get a fully expanded version of configure's output?

Comment: Hi!  Could you explain why you'd like to do that?  Your question sounds like you are trying to solve another problem the hard way.  (For instance if you want to retrieve the expanded value of a variable such as `$datadir`, there are simpler ways to to it.)

Comment: i want to create shell script templates independent of the linux system they are running on
so i can create scripts for setting up a server and using the same script for a second instance which only needs modification of a few parameters
the template engine im using just search/replace the script's variables
to do this i need to initialize the engine with all the variables or they wont get replaced

Comment: @adl can you explain what is the 'easy' way to deal with it. I am also struggling with this problem

Answer (score 8):

The Autoconf manual (I cannot recall or find exactly where) recommends to "manually" do such a kind of variable substitution from within a Makefile.in (or .am if you happen to use Automake):

Makefile.in

```
[...]
foo.sh: foo.sh.in
        $(SED) \
            -e 's|[@]prefix@|$(prefix)|g' \
            -e 's|[@]exec_prefix@|$(exec_prefix)|g' \
            -e 's|[@]bindir@|$(bindir)|g' \
            -e 's|[@]datarootdir@|$(datarootdir)|g' \
            < "$<" > "$@"
[...]
```

foo.sh.in

```
#!/bin/sh
datarootdir=@datarootdir@
du "$datarootdir"
```