# How to full expand variables in autoconf?

Tags: linux, packaging, autoconf

In this example:

```
configure.ac: 
  ...
  AC_CONFIG_FILES([script1])
  AC_OUTPUT

script1.in: 
  #!/bin/bash
  ...
  config=@datadir@/blah
```

This `@datadir@` is expanded to `${prefix}/share`, is there any way to expand it to `/usr/local/share`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how get fully expanded variables out of configure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440873/how-get-fully-expanded-variables-out-of-configure)

Answer (score 2):

You can use adl_RECURSIVE_EVAL from the autoconf archive to fully expand paths.